# Control audio playing in background android

Tags: android, audio

Can I provide play / pause / next and previous control for audio playing in background?
my app play stream audio in Asynck class which make the audio play in background.

I want to allow user to control that playing as in iPhone control center or as music player of samsung devices

plz , help find what I'm looking for

I used the code on section **Use Hardware Playback Control Keys to Control Your App’s Audio Playback**  in doc , but nothing work with me

set up the receiver

```
<receiver android:name=".RemoteControlReceiver">
    <intent-filter>
        <action android:name="android.intent.action.MEDIA_BUTTON" />
    </intent-filter>
</receiver>

public class RemoteControlReceiver extends BroadcastReceiver {
    @Override
    public void onReceive(Context context, Intent intent) {
        if (Intent.ACTION_MEDIA_BUTTON.equals(intent.getAction())) {
            KeyEvent event = (KeyEvent)intent.getParcelableExtra(Intent.EXTRA_KEY_EVENT);
            if (KeyEvent.KEYCODE_MEDIA_PLAY == event.getKeyCode()) {
                // Handle key press.
            }
        }
    }
}
```

but registering the RemoteControl is not accepted by code

```
AudioManager am = mContext.getSystemService(Context.AUDIO_SERVICE);

am.registerMediaButtonEventReceiver(RemoteControlReceiver);
```

thanks in advance

Comment: Please be more specific. _"nothing work with me"_ doesn't really tell us anything.

Comment: What does _"is not accepted by code"_ mean? Does it not compile? Does it crash? Does it give incorrect results..? What error messages, if any, do you get? You need to be a lot clearer when you describe your problem.

Comment: @Michael it give compile error in the parameter of registerMedia .. is the code correct? what exactly is RemoteControlReceiver ? is it instance of class?